# RoR - NoMethodError, undefined method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, methods

I have created an app with simple login authentication, it is actually a twitter clone. The user logs in and access the pages, etc.

But when the user posts something from there profile. It gives an error

```
NoMethodError in RibbitsController#create
undefined method `id=' for nil:NilClass
```

The error is around line 5:

```
class RibbitsController < ApplicationController

 def create
   @ribbit = Ribbit.create(user_ribbits)
   @ribbit.userid = current_user.id

   if @ribbit.save
       redirect_to current_user 
   else
       flash[:error] = "Problem!"
       redirect_to current_user
   end
 end

 private

 def user_ribbits
      params.require(:ribbit).permit(:content, :userid)
    end
end
```

The request given to app:

```
Request
```

Parameters:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"dwVmjDNO4GOowphGFgChMDBxBfvka+M/xSUHvJMECzwxtv4NF6OuWtiaX74NLz91OwQJ9T9+wm7yMiPQ0BLpGA==",
 "ribbit"=>{"content"=>"hi. test.\r\n"},
 "commit"=>"Ribbit!"}
```

The sessions controller:

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController

  def new
  end

  def create
   user = User.find_by_username(params[:username])
    if user && user.authenticate(params[:password])
        session[:userid] = user.id
        redirect_to rooturl, notice: "Logged in!"
    else
        flash[:error] = "Wrong Username or Password."
        redirect_to root_url
    end
  end

  def destroy
   session[:userid] = nil
    redirect_to root_url, notice: "Logged out."
  end

end
```

The users controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

 def new
     @user = User.new
 end

 def create
   @user = User.create(user_params)

   if @user.save
    session[:user_id] = @user.id
     redirect_to @user, notice: "Thank you for signing up!"
   else
     render 'new'
   end
 end

 def show
   @user = User.find(params[:id])
   @ribbit = Ribbit.new
 end

 private

 def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:name, :username, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :avatar_url)
    end

end
```

And the application controller

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  private

 def current_user
   @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
  end

  helper_method :current_user
end
```

I would really appreciate it if you guys would help!

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure your `Ribbit` is beings saved?

Comment: not sure if it is the reason, but you use both `:userid` and `:user_id`. probably want to stick to `user_id`, because it's conventional to use this kind of foreign key name

Comment: try placing debugger in the `create` action of `RibbitsContoller` and see if you are getting `current_user` there

Comment: Plus, are you sure you gave correct error message? You're trying to call `userid=` method instead of `id=`.

Comment: I think, session[:user_id] is not defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to assign `current_user.id`to `@ribbit.userid` without ensuring that `current_user` is set. 'current_user' would be set only if a user has been previously saved before.

Therefore, you need either to make sure that an authenticated user is trying to create a `Ribbit`, or if you consider the `userid` as a non mandatory field, you can simply change your line 5 by:

```
@ribbit.userid = current_user.id unless current_user.blank?
```

If you only want authenticated user to create Ribbits, then consider using a gem to handle authentication such as [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise). You could then use `before_filter :authenticate_user!` in your controller to make sure users are properly authenticated.